# PHP MySQLi - WHERE "calculated value is smaller than" not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I got this code:

```
$userquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, 
                    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$latme') ) *
                cos( radians( latitude ) ) *
                cos( radians( longitude ) -
                radians('$lonme') ) +
                sin( radians('$latme') ) *
                sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )
                AS distance
FROM `eintrag` 
ORDER BY distance ASC");
```

and get results with distance from 0.1 till 999.

Now when I try to get only results where distance is below 20:

```
FROM `eintrag` 
WHERE distance < 20
ORDER BY distance ASC");
```

then it's not working, I don't get any results.

How to do it right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't repeat an alias defined in a select in a where clause at the same level.  But, MySQL has an overloaded `HAVING` operator which you may use:

```
FROM `eintrag` 
HAVING distance < 20
ORDER BY distance
```

The only other two options here would repeating the entire Haversine formula in the `WHERE` clause (ugly), or wrapping your current query and then using a subquery (less performant).